# Passing values to bunch of controllers in JavaFX dinamically

Tags: java, jpa, javafx

I have a JavaFX project with JPA connection.
At the beginning the user must choose whether to register or log in.
When the user tries to log in, the program checks for an existing entity.
If it exists, the user can pass to the main scene.

During the scene-switching the name of the user is passed, so on the main screen's controller can get the entity the same way as I mentioned above.

In my application, handling the entity of the user is the key, so I always need an entity on every controller class.

Do I need to pass the username all along in my app at every scene swith? Or is it an easier and more practical way to do this?

This is how I pass my username String to another Controller:

```
   Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
   Stage newStage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader((getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("views/mainScreen.fxml")));
   Scene newScene = new Scene(loader.load());
   loader.<MainScreen>getController().setUser(username);

   newStage.setScene(newScene);
   newStage.show();
```

And this is the body of the receiving function:

```
userEntity = userService.isRegistered(username);
```

If this is the practical way for this, can you please help me to write a scene switcher function? So I could avoid code duplications and keep the DRY  principle.

I have a switcher without passing any information:

```
public void sceneSwitch(Stage stage, String fxml, ActionEvent event){

    try {
        Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
        stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        Scene newScene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("views/" + fxml + ".fxml"))));
        stage.setScene(newScene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to maintain user name across multiple controller, one idea is to maintain a `global` variable for user name. In this way you don't have to modify your controller classes by adding additional `getters` and `setter` for user name

```
public class Global
{
    private static String userName;

    public static void setUserName(final String userName)
    {
        Global.userName = userName;
    }

    public static String getUserName()
    {
       return Global.userName;
    }

}
```

Just before loading other `fxml` set its value

```
   Global.setUserName("user name here");
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader((getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("views/mainScreen.fxml")));
   Scene newScene = new Scene(loader.load());
```

And in side loaded controller you can simply get it

```
  Global.getUserName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make all your controllers implement an interface, say:

```
public interface UserAware {

    public void setUser(String username) ;

}
```

and maybe use an abstract class to implement:

```
public abstract class UserAwareController {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void setUser(String username) {
        userEntity = userService.isRegistered(username);
    }

    // ...
}
```

which all your controllers can subclass.

Then you can write a utility method to avoid the repetitive code:

```
public class FXMLLoaders {

    public static Parent loadWithUsername(String resource, String username) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resource));
        Parent ui = loader.load();
        UserAware controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setUser(username);
        return ui ;
    }
}
```

And then of course just

```
Scene newScene = new Scene(FXMLLoaders.loadWithUsername("views/mainScreen.fxml", username));
```